# ASP.Net MVC Data Formatting

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, layout, formatting

Say I have a database table like the following:

```
FileID | FileName | FileSize | Group
-------------------------------------
1        test.txt   100        Group1
2        test2.txt  100        Group1
3        test3.txt  100        Group2
```

What would be the best way to display this data with an MVC view in the style of:

Group 1

Table Containing Group1 files

---

Group 2

Table containing Group1 files

---

What I am getting it, is when I group the results by Group via a linq to sql query, how can I efficiently display the file lists in sections.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick sample...  I'm assuming a strongly typed model that contains a list of Groups with the corresponding files...

**MODEL**

```
public class Groups
{
    public List<Files> GroupFiles { get; set; }
    public String Name{ get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public String FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<%
foreach(var group in myModel.FileGroups)
{
%>
      <h2><%= group.Name %></h2>
      <table>
<%   
    foreach(var file in group.Files)
    { %>

         <tr>
             <td><%= file.FileID %></td>
             <td><%= file.FileName %></td>
             <td><%= file.FileSize %></td>
         </tr>

    <%
    } %>
</table>
<%
}
%>
```

Comment: Looks good, could you give an example of the extension method needed?

Comment: Drop the extension method idea... It'll just be easier if the code that populates your model already does that work for you.